# Routing API project and Web Application project in the same domain (Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, azure, asp.net-core

### Background

I have two separate projects in my solution. One of them (the web application project) is responsible to show the landing page (on the root of the domain, say www.example.com) and a documentation for the API (say www.example.com/documentation).

The other project is responsible for the API itself. It's path must be www.example.com/api/v1/ to ensure compatibility with our previous software.

We made this way to be able to publish updates to any of the projects without the need to publish the entire solution, and of course, for organization.

### Problem

I don't get how to configure the applications to run on Azure on the same domain with different routes, and I'm stating to fear that it is not possible.

I already tried to configure a subdomain (say api.example.com/v1), but it can't be done because we will break the compatibility with our current clients.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370425/web-api-2-project-and-mvc-5-website-project-in-same-domain) is almost what I'm looking for, but it does not show how to do on Azure, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447921/how-to-deploy-a-solution-with-two-projects-to-azure-app-service) is on Azure but using subdomains.

Comment: Looks like your solution is here: [Web Api and Project on Azure Same domain][1]     [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site

Comment: @QaiserMehmood LOL what search engine did you use? +1

Comment: @QaiserMehmood Gona try that, if it works I will comment back.

Comment: Great, it's google to find it.

Comment: @QaiserMehmood How I can't find that.... I searched for hours.... Guess is the search terms I was using.

Comment: Is this mvc with webapi deployed on azure. From maintenace, perspective later, you can just publish the  api part.

Comment: This is query I used to search:) hosting asp.net and web api on same domain on azure

Answer (score 0):

- First: you have to create 2 folders, 1 for your web api and the
  second for your web app
- second: you have to set the two folders as an    application.

after doing those two steps you can acces to the two folder by puting:

- www.yourdomaine.com(or another)/nameofyourfolder

good luck

Comment: Where did i create those folders? On azure or in the solution?

Comment: You should do it in Azure.